# Is there a way to remove values from a pandas data frame with less than 4 decimal places and end up with an overwrite of the originally loaded data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with 200 entries that has some values rounded to 4 decimal places and some values rounded to 2 decimal places. How can I clean the dataset by removing all rows which have values with decimal places less than 4 and end up with an overwrite of the originally loaded data?

For example: a column with a list of numbers with varying numbers of decimal places: 0.1565,0.1536,0.3697, 0.13, 0.35, 0.3654, 0.88,0.3344. but anything with less than 4 dp is not accurate enough, so I want to filter dataset to only have rows with 4 dp, i.e. : 0.1565,0.1536,0.3697, 0.3654.... etc.and end up with an overwrite of the originally loaded data

Answer (score 1):

Other solution is using some math manipulation, checking for remainder

```
df['new'] = df['old'] * 10000
df['check'] = 1  
df.loc[(df['new'] % 10) == 0, 'check'] = 0
df = df.loc[df['check']==1, :].copy()
```

Comment: nice trick! I like it

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert your data from float to string
2. Calculate the length of each string
3. Select row with length = 6 (0.xxxx)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[0.1565,0.1536,0.36975, 0.13, 0.35, 0.3654, 0.88,0.3344]})
df['string_value'] = df['value'].astype(str) # it will automaticaly remove trailing zeros
df['digit_length'] = df['string_value'].str.len() # calculate length of each value
df = df[df['digit_length']==6] # filter the dataframe
df.drop(columns=['string_value','digit_length'],inplace=True) # remove columns
```

Comment: Thank you! I am still however, not quite sure how to store it in the column with the same name as in my data. In other word, to overwrite the originally loaded data with the filter applied? Thanks again

Comment: i already edited my answer to suit you need